# Function to return a list of tuples from a list of dictionaries does not work when the dictionary has all the information required to extract

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, dictionary, information-extraction

have a list of dictionaries, each dictionary contains:

First name
Middle name
Last name
Title
Address
Email address
Loyalty program
For one client.

Some of this information may be missing

```
segment = [{'first-name': 'Elsa', 'last-name': 'Frost', 'title': 'Princess', 'address': '33 Castle Street, London', 'loyalty-program': 'Gold'}, {'first-name': 'Anna', 'last-name': 'Frost', 'title': 'Princess', 'loyalty-program': 'Platinum'}, {'first-name': 'Harry', 'middle-name': 'Harold', 'last-name': 'Hare', 'title': 'Mr', 'email-address': 'harry.harold@hare.name', 'loyalty-program': 'Silver'}]
```

For clients who have a physical address, I need to extract a list of tuples. Each tuple represents one client and contains their title, first name, middle name, and last name in that order if defined, and the mailing address.

My code appears to be working in some instances but not others.

When:

```
segment = [{'first-name': 'Elsa', 'last-name': 'Frost', 'title': 'Princess', 'address': '33 Castle Street, London', 'loyalty-program': 'Gold'}, {'first-name': 'Anna', 'last-name': 'Frost', 'title': 'Princess', 'loyalty-program': 'Platinum'}, {'first-name': 'Harry', 'middle-name': 'Harold', 'last-name': 'Hare', 'title': 'Mr', 'email-address': 'harry.harold@hare.name', 'loyalty-program': 'Silver'}]
```

The code appears to work

```
def process_clients(segment):

    new_list = []
    new_tuple =()
    for x in segment: #Focuses on the dictionary 
        #Selects the name and address for clients with a registered address 
        if "address" in x:
            if "middle-name" in x:
                new_tuple += (x["title"] + " " + x["first-name"] + " " + x["middle-name"] + " " + x["last-name"]), (x["address"])
            else:
                new_tuple += (x["title"] + " " + x["first-name"] + " "  + x["last-name"]), (x["address"])
                new_list.append(new_tuple)

    return new_list

process_clients(segment)
```

Output:

```
[[('Princess Elsa Frost', '33 Castle Street, London '),
 ('Princess Elsa Frost',
  '33 Castle Street, London ',
  'Princess Anna Frost',
  '34 Castle Street, London ')]
process_clients(segment)
```

However, if an element other than the middle name is missing, a key error is generated. I think it would be possible to create a function that generates a tuple from every possible combination of parts of the name, How could I go about this? Or even better, how could I construct a more concise function

Is there a way of creating a function more concisely,

Comment: Just to make sure, if the address is missing it shouldn't be added to the end result, right?

Comment: Yes, you got it :)

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you want right you just need this with your function:

```
segment = [{'first-name': 'Elsa', 'last-name': 'Frost', 'title': 'Princess', 'address': '33 Castle Street, London', 'loyalty-program': 'Gold'}, {'first-name': 'Anna', 'last-name': 'Frost', 'title': 'Princess', 'loyalty-program': 'Platinum'}, {'first-name': 'Harry', 'middle-name': 'Harold', 'last-name': 'Hare', 'title': 'Mr', 'email-address': 'harry.harold@hare.name', 'loyalty-program': 'Silver'}]

def process_clients(segment):
    for client in segment:
        if "address" in client:
            yield (' '.join(filter(bool, map(client.get, ("first-name", "middle-name", "last-name")))), client["address"])

list(process_clients(segment))
```

EDIT: If you'd rather return a `list` than a `generator` from `process_clients`, you could do 2 things:

```
def process_clients(segment):
    new_list = []
    for client in segment:
        if "address" in client:
            new_list.append(
                (' '.join(filter(bool, map(client.get, ("first-name", "middle-name", "last-name")))),
                client["address"])
            )
    return new_list
```

or

```
def process_clients(segment):
    return [(' '.join(filter(bool, map(client.get, ("first-name", "middle-name", "last-name")))), client["address"]) for client in segment if "address" in client]
```

Comment: This is brilliant and exactly what I needed

However, even with the last line to convert back into a list

The code is returning a generator instead of a list